# Who certifies the hechsher magen David with a K replacing the right side?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, hechsher-certification

[image: hechsher]

This symbol appears on Trader Joe's Organic Tahini.

I have searched in a lot places, but cannot find it. The product is made in Greece. Anyone know who gives this hechsher and if it is reliable?

Comment: I've also been wondering about this hechsher on the Trader Joe's Organic Tahini. Did you ever find out more about it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Trader Joes](https://www.traderjoes.com/PDF/Kosher-Index-print.pdf) shows this hechsher as

> 79 Kosher in Greece Vassileos Irakliou 26, 54624. Thessaloniki, Greece
>   +302310-275.701 Rabbi Rav Shitrit Eliahu jctrabbi.saloniki@gmail.com

[Kosher Food In Greece](http://www.kosherdelight.com/Koshergreece.htm) entry is ten years old.

> THESSALONIKI
>
> Monastirioton Synagogue 35, Sygrou St. (open primarily on High
>   Holidays) Thessaloniki, Greece Tel: Fax: Email: Website: Rabbi Eliyahu
>   Shitrit , jctrabbi.saloniki@gmail.com work: 2310221124 Home:
>   2310223921 Mobile: 6936896094 Kosher food: You may order kosher meals
>   through the Rabbi Mikvah: Please call Rabanit Shitrit: 2310223921
>
> Last updated on: December 5, 2007

Answer (score 3):

Eliyahu Shitrit is no longer in Thessaloniki but in Volos. There is NO Shomer Shabbat community anywhere in Greece. The only reliable Kosher restaurant located in Athens, Greece is operated by Rabbi Mendel Hendel, Chabad Shaliach.  The chicken/meat products he uses in his restaurant are imported from France. He also sells them to the public. All the condiments are from Israel but brought into Greece in containers loads from France. He bakes off his own bread & pita.  Chabad **DOES NOT** rely or recommend any products approved as kosher by any rabbis in the community. If you have questions call Chabad.    **DO NOT BE MISLED** by any entity in the US stating that this certification is acceptable at anytime on any product.

Comment: Can you please provide references for your information? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The certification is called Kosher in Greece. Rabbi is Rabbi Eliyahu Shitrit.

I will add in more information after Purim.

Comment: it's after Purim...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות It might have been a Purimspiel...